# Create N arrays of length M where the sequence is increased by 1 on each array

Tags: python, arrays

Good morning,

Given two numbers (a,b), I should create 'a' different list of length 'b' where the sequence of each list is increased by one.

For example :

1,2 =>`[[0,1]]`

2,2 = > `[[0,1], [1,2]]`

I am trying to write the following function:

```
def increase_arrays(arrays, length):
    result = [[i for i in range(length)] for i in range(arrays)]
    return result

increase_arrays(2,3)
=> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

I can't see how to modify my code so the second array is `[1,2,3]`.
Could anyone help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have famous duplicated index problem, you have 2 indexes `i`.

Below is the code that you need:

```
def increase_arrays(arrays, length):
    result = [[i + j for i in range(length)] for j in range(arrays)]
    return result
```

`increase_arrays(2, 3)` returns `[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve it with:

```
def increase_arrays(arrays, length):
    return [list(range(i,length+i)) for i in range(arrays)]
```

Comment: This is the solution but it much less readable than your previous code. Plus dependently how you use it, this could be slower because cast to `list` is quite expensive operation on the long ranges.

Comment: @Dmytro. Are you implying that converting a sequence of known length will be slower than converting an equivalent generator expression? I.e., that `list(range(...)))` will every be slower than `[x + y for x in range(...)]`? Because I don't think that's right.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It was my bad. You are right that `list(range(...))` would be faster than list comprehension. I tested with different Pythons but I still do think that the initial code was more readable. At the moment, if I see function in several months, I am not sure that it will take 1 second to figure out what code does even it is one-liner.

Comment: @Dmytro. I think good variable names would go a long way to alleviating that. E.g. `i` -> `offset`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a numpy solution, just for fun:

```
np.arange(arrays)[:,np.newaxis] + np.arange(length)[np.newaxis,:]
```